# Date custom format Angular Js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am new to Angular, and using angular with rails. I searched in many places, but didn't get the answer in required format

I have a field 'available_date' in my database and a value is loaded in the html view using angular js.

I want to display my date in the super script format, for eg: if I have the date `22/02/2016` I have to show like, `22nd February 2016` is there any way in angular js to do this?

```
In rails, it can be done by,

<p><%= user.available_date.strftime("%B %e") %><sup><%#= num_ordinalize(user.available_date.day) %></sup></p>
<p data-ng-bind="user.available_date | 'I want filter here' ">
```

But I want in Angular Js.

```
I/p => '22/02/2016'
O/p => '22nd February 2016'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please try searching first ... there are numerous similar questions. Just look at ***Related Links*** on right side of this page for example

Comment: Yes, I searched in many places, but didn't get the answer in that format.

Comment: You can use {{ dateVariable | date:'DD-MMM-YYYY' }} in your view (say HTML) directly